# Ignore numbers while comparing strings

Tags: python, string, compare

Im new to python.I want to compare two strings .but the numbers in them should be ignored.

Eg. Want to compare "addf.0987.addf" with "addf.1222.addf'

Can u help?

Comment: I suggest you add a python tag to this, unless you really want the answer in any language

Comment: Help with what? Have you tried anything before asking for help?

Comment: So, your example should return True?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all()`:

```
>>> one = "addf.0987.addf"
>>> two = "addf.1222.addf"
>>> all(i[0] == i[1] for i in zip(one, two) if not i[0].isdigit())
True
```

Or:

```
>>> one = "addf.0987.addf"
>>> two = "addf.1222.addf"
>>> [i for i in one if not i.isdigit()] == [i for i in two if not i.isdigit()]
True
```

Answer (score 1):

here it goes.

```
def is_equal(m, n):
    if len(m) != len(n):
        return False
    for ind in xrange(len(m)):
        if m[ind].isdigit() and n[ind].isdigit():
            continue
        if m[ind] != n[ind]:
            return False
    else:
        return True


is_equal("addf.0987.addf", "addf.1222.add")    # It returns False.
is_equal("addf.11.addf", "addf.11.addf")       # It returns True.
is_equal("addf.11.addf", "addf.22.addf")       # it returns True.
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has really easy and elegant ways of comparing strings, or slices of strings (for example see Haidro's answer). It is one of the things I like so much about Python. But if you want something really silly:

```
    a1 = 'addf.1234.addf'
    a2 = 'addf.4376.addf'
    a3 = 'xxxx.1234.xxxx'

    my_compare = lambda x: (x[:4], x[-4:])

    my_compare(a1) == my_compare(a2)
    => True
    my_compare(a1) == my_compare(a3)
    => False
```

(Note this is just for fun :p)